# Reduce voltage ripple in wall power supply and buck converters

Tags: power-supply, power, buck, step-down

For my project I choose a wall AC/DC power supply ([AEJ160PS12](https://assets.rs-online.com/v1675774181/Datasheets/aac6ab052f8046ef04ca013c2a633cec.pdf)) with output voltage at 12V and intend to use some buck converters to step down from 12V to 6V and 3.3V. The chosed buck converters is [TPS565242DRLR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps565242.pdf). The 12V, 6V and 3.3V power supplies will be used to power some actuators.

On the datasheet of the AC/DC power supply it's written that at the output there is a voltage ripple of 1%, circa 120mV. Considering that I'll use the buck converter, I would like to reduce as much as possible the voltage ripple from the AC/DC power supply in order to avoid that the ripple will be transferred also to the buck converter. Furthermore, I would like to reduce the ripple in order to minimize the fluactuation in the power supply of the actuators.

The picture below shows the configuration to obtain 6V at the output of the buck converter:
[image: Buck 6V]

Here to obtain 3.3V:
[image: Buck 3.3V]

Here are my questions:

- What are the options to reduce voltage ripple?
- Should I add a PI filter to the input of the buck converter or to the output?
- In case I need to use a PI filter, how can I calculate the values? I read about a cutoff frequency to calculate the value of the capacitor, but how can I find it? I know the buck switching frequency, which is about 470kHz, and the resonant frequency of the 3.3uH inductor is 26.5MHz and 23MHz for 2.2uH.
- Should I also consider other aspects, like EMI or ESD? For instance for ESD I considered TVS diodes.

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, I also have other actuators that needs 12V. I would like to reduce the ripple in order to minimize the fluctuation of the power supply of the many actuators. Furthermore I don't want to introduce much noise into the system

Comment: Little or none of the input ripple will be transferred through the DCDC converter (which is a voltage regulator surrounded by filtering capacitors). Instead, the buck regulators will generate their own switching noise, which you get to decide when you pick the inductors and capacitors.

Comment: (@user1850479 *Little or none of the input ripple will be transferred* I wondered just how much. PS is about 111 kHz, buck at 600 to 200 kHz. No input transient response shown. Then again, what's 1 % ripple to an actuator?)

Comment: I think with so many parallel ceramic input and then output capacitors even a bad regulator will handle a 1% ripple down to the point where it's irrelevant compared to the buck converter noise.